# Selenium c# find link in table

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find a link in a table which is positioned in column 1 by data in column 11

After much hunting around I have found the following snippit of code adapted for my needs

```
        IWebElement table = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='NewBusinessDetailRecords']"));
        IList <IWebElement> rows = table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));

        foreach (IWebElement row in table)
        {
            rows = table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
            IList<IWebElement> cells = row.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));
            if (cells[10].Text.Equals("103"))
            {
                cells[0].Click();
            }
        }
```

However the foreach statement is not working highlighting the table with error

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement' because 'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Several posts suggest I need to use IEnumerable (Also some which suggest this should be automatic) but I haven't managed to work out to implement this into my code.

Any help is appreciated

EDIT:

Example HTML from 1 table row

```
<table id="NewBusinessDetailRecords" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;" class="listviewgrid">  
<thead> ... </thead>    
<tbody>        
<tr id="0" class="datagriddetail">      
<td style="text-align: center">            
<a href="" accesskey="1" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;" onclick="CopyNewBusinessDetailRecord(0, 0, 1083406, 14436); return false;" title="Matched to Invoice with ID = 14436; Client with ID = 1083406"><img src="../../images/icons/invoice.png" border="0"></a>              </td>         
<td> Test1 Case1 </td>      
<td> Invoice </td>      
<td> GBP </td>      
<td style="text-align: right"> 600.00 </td>      
<td> 0% </td>      
<td style="text-align: right"> 600.00 </td>      
<td> </td>      
<td> Company Name </td>      
<td> UserName</td>      
<td> 103 </td>     
<td> </td>      
<td> </td>      
<td> </td>      
<td style="text-align: center">            </td>    
</tr>        <tr id="0" class="datagriddetail">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to iterate for each `<tr>` in the `<table>`. You should be iterating through `rows`, not `table`:

```
foreach (IWebElement row in rows)
```

Also, you'll need to remove this extraneous line: `rows = table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));`. Once "inside" the foreach loop, the `row` variable contains the `<tr>` `IWebElement` to be processed.

---

Based on your sample HTML, I also have a few suggestions:

- I would avoid using XPath when possible. In your case, simply select by the id.

  ```
  IWebElement table = driver.FindElement(By.Id("NewBusinessDetailRecords"));
  ```
- Add validation before indexing `cells`. This will prevent the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

  ```
  if (cells.Count > 10 && cells[10].Text.Equals("103"))
  ```

---

Full code:

```
IWebElement table = driver.FindElement(By.Id("NewBusinessDetailRecords"));
IList<IWebElement> rows = table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));

foreach (IWebElement row in rows)
{
    IList<IWebElement> cells = row.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));
    if (cells.Count > 10 && cells[10].Text.Equals("103"))
    {
        cells[0].Click();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have this error because `foreach` is only working with `IEnumerable` types

`foreach (IWebElement row in table)` would definately fail, because `table` is `IWebElement` and it is obviously a single object.

What you need here is just remove unnecessary `foreach` loop, like this (row 0 column 10):

```
var row = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("table#NewBusinessDetailRecords tr#0"));
var cells = row.FindElements(By.TagName("td")).ToList();
if (cells[10].Text.Equals("103"))
{
    cells[10].Click();
}
```

I can't tell you for sure, because I don't have html code of the element you need click, but I think all your code can be replaced with this:

```
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("103")).Click();
```

Or if you you want to specify only part of link text:

```
driver.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText("10")).Click();
```

Comment: This solution is not working for me as I am getting an ArgumentOurOfRangeExpection on the if line. I'll append some sample Html to my question

Comment: I couldn't find link code in html. I consider it looks like <a href="url">103</a>. In that case the last code snippet should work: driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("103")).Click();.

Comment: The link is embedded in the <ahref... line so the link test is not 103 unfortuntely

Comment: Your edited code also falls over on the cells = row.Findelements with 'List<IWebElement>' does not contain a definition for 'FindElements' and no extension method 'FindElements' accepting a first argument of type 'List<IWebElement>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Sorry for misprint. Didn't have a compiler. Can you try it now?

Comment: Thanks for your continued trying with this. Its now throwing an invalid or illegal selector on the first line

Comment: It is because you have two 'tr' elements with id='0'

Comment: I have 8 'tr' elements with id of '0'

Comment: From W3 ([link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp)): _The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document)_. So the html page you are testing has some weird format.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145117/discussion-between-n-m-and-smithy7876).